# Fluent UDF in C, I need every time step to read initial X and Y coordinates and not the newly calculated ones

Tags: c, user-defined-functions, fluent

Below is a UDF that I have been working on for rotating the points of an airfoil. This code works in my previous application where I calculated a new Y value based on X, but now I just want to read the X and Y coordinates, rotate them, then output the rotated coordinates. This code works but it is calculating each time step based on the previously rotated points (ie it rotates the coordinates then instead of calculating the next time step from the initial coordinates it calculates them off the previously rotated coordinates causing major over rotation) instead of the original baseline coordinates thus creating too much rotation of the coordinates. Can anyone help so that it always reads the original X and Y coordinates?

Thanks,

Thomas

```c
#include "udf.h" 

#define FTT 0.4 

#define chord 1.00000

/*upper surface*/

DEFINE_GRID_MOTION(Up, domain, dt, time, dtime) 

{
 
Thread *tf = DT_THREAD (dt); 

face_t f; 

Node *node_p; 

real x,y,theta,x_s,y_s,T_max,Tmorph,freq,omega,xuc,yuc, Rux,Ruy,rcux,rcuy; 

int n; 

freq = 0.2; 

omega = 2 * M_PI * freq;

Tmorph= 0.0555555794; 

T_max = FTT+Tmorph; 

x_s = 0.25*chord; 

y_s = 0; 

SET_DEFORMING_THREAD_FLAG (THREAD_T0 (tf)); 

begin_f_loop (f, tf) 

{ 

f_node_loop (f, tf, n) 

{ 

node_p = F_NODE(f, tf, n);

x = NODE_X(node_p);

y = NODE_Y(node_p);

if (NODE_POS_NEED_UPDATE (node_p)) 

{ 

NODE_POS_UPDATED (node_p); 


if ( x < x_s) { 

if ( CURRENT_TIME >= FTT && CURRENT_TIME <= T_max) { 

theta = omega * (CURRENT_TIME - FTT);

xuc = x - x_s;

yuc = y - y_s;

Rux = ((xuc * cos(-theta)) + (yuc * sin(-theta)));

Ruy = ((xuc * -sin(-theta)) + (yuc * cos(-theta)));

rcux = Rux + x_s;

rcuy = Ruy + y_s;

NODE_Y (node_p) = rcuy ; 

} 
/*morphing stops*/ 

if ( CURRENT_TIME > T_max) { 

theta = omega * Tmorph;

xuc = x - x_s;

yuc = y - y_s;

Rux = ((xuc * cos(-theta)) + (yuc * sin(-theta)));

Ruy = ((xuc * -sin(-theta)) + (yuc * cos(-theta)));

rcux = Rux + x_s;

rcuy = Ruy + y_s;

NODE_Y (node_p) = rcuy; 

} 

}
 
}
 
end_f_loop (f, tf); 

}
 
}
 
}
```

Comment: What is your meaning of UDF? Is it really user-defined functions (as tagged)? What is this `udf.h` header file? What is `DEFINE_GRID_MOTION`?

Comment: DEFINE_GRID_MOTION is for the control of the mesh motion in fluent. This is a code for a user defined function that allows for the control of the flow domain during a CFD calculation in ANSYS Fluent.